# How to add 2d array in sqlite IOS?

Tags: ios, sqlite

i have array namely _twoArray it contains data something like below

```
ha ha 2d array(
    (
    "Anand Kapadiya",
    "Alok Darji",
    "Akash Parikh",
    "Ajay Desai",
    "Aysu Can",
    "Ayegba James",
    "Ashish Modi",
    "Arks Patel",
    "Archit Patel",
    "Anzey Khodorovskyy"
),
    (
    "12/01",
    "08/13/1990",
    "12/09/1989",
    "05/22/1988",
    "04/14/1992",
    "12/15/1905",
    "09/08",
    "05/27/1990",
    "05/22/1990",
    "02/06"
)
```

)

i have database with one table and 2 fields one is Names and another is birth dates how can i add birth dates and names in database from this 2d array i am trying following code

```
 for (id obj in _twoArray) 
{

 sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int x;

    char *update = "insert into PersonNamesAndBirthDates (Names,Birthdates) values(? ?);";
    x = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, update, -1, &stmt, nil);

    if (x == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"PersonNamesAndBirthDates is -->%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj]);

        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, NULL,-1, NULL);

    }
    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE){}
    NSLog(@"Error: ");
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

}
```

plz suggest me something or if this is not possible then tell me how can i add 2 different array in table at same time

Comment: u success in fetch value from this array ??

Comment: i have 2 array one for name and another for birthdates when i added them seperatedly in database then it get inserted in wrong way so i made 2d array and trying to add it. its not going in if (x== SQLITE_OK)

Comment: [mainArray indexAtObject:0]; this return array name and [mainArray indexAtObject:0]; this return array of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your _twoArray contains two object which are in turn NSArray.  Now it is fixed that you will have always two array within one array, then try this

```
NSArray *nameArr = [_twoArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *bdArr   = [_twoArray objectAtIndex:1];
if (sqlite3_open([databaseFilePath UTF8String], &database1) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    for (int i = 0; i< [nameArr count]; i++)
    {

        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
        int x;

        char *update = "insert into PersonNamesAndBirthDates (Names,Birthdates) values(? ?);";
        x = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, update, -1, &stmt, nil);

        if (x == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"PersonName is -->%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[nameArr objectAtIndex:i]]);
            NSLog(@"BirthDates is -->%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[bdArr objectAtIndex:i]]);



            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[nameArr objectAtIndex:i]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[bdArr objectAtIndex:i]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);

        }
        if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE){}
        NSLog(@"Error: ");
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database1);
}
```

Comment: i had 2 separate array but i mixed them cus when i use individual insert statment for each array then it get added to table but in wrong way like first all names in name fild and then birthdates in birthdates they are not getting add in straight to each other

Comment: its not going in if (x == sqlite_ok) statment

Comment: Hey have you opened your connection to database ?

Comment: yes yes when i add individual for both array then it get added but in that was it get stored in wrong way in database i want name and and in another field birthdate of that person

Comment: thank you very much Bhargavi it worked im also from Gujarat jay jay garvi gujarat :)

Comment: @Desai Its my pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your array contain two objects which are array type.

```
 for (int i=0;i<[[_twoArray objectAtIndex:0] count];i++) 
{

 sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int x;

    char *update = "insert into PersonNamesAndBirthDates (Names,Birthdates) values(? ?);";
    x = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, update, -1, &stmt, nil);

    if (x == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"PersonName:%@ BirthDate:%@",[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_twoArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:i]],[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_twoArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:i]]);

        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_twoArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:i]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, NULL,-1, NULL);

    }
    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE){}
    NSLog(@"Error: ");
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in the way you are trying to, as your `for` loop is providing you a array at a time not the variables. You can use following two ways:

1. create two arrays `name` and `dob` and add records respectively on same index then use `for` loop for the index of any array and use 2 string variable to store data of same index and then use these to create query
2. Or you can create a `NSDictionary` in which you can store, `name` and `dob`, such as

   ```
       NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
       while (records) {
           NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"Mr. X", @"name"
                                       @"13/12/82", @"dob"
                                       nil];
           [array addObject:dictionary];
           records--;
       }
   ```

   And then create each query for index. to retrieve dictionary, values and to create query you use following code,

   ```
       for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
           NSString *userName = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
           NSString *dateOfBirth = [dict valueForKey:@"dob"];
           //write query here
       }
   ```